# UTL_FILE options ORACLE

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a function that contains calls to `UTL_FILE` package. This reads data from a table and then writes a file, in a Linux path.

The file is correctly generated, but data inside it appears in various lines.
I need to write the data on the same line in the file.

Is this posible?

Does UTL_FILE have an option to do this?

```
  FUNCTION f_hisr_archive_name
    (New_File          IN VARCHAR2
    ,New_Path          IN VARCHAR2
    ,ARCHIVE_STRING    IN VARCHAR2
    ,hisr_freq_rec     IN HISRFrequency%ROWTYPE
    ) RETURN INTEGER

  IS
  BEGIN

    IF ( ( RTRIM(New_File) = RTRIM(File) ) AND
         ( RTRIM(New_Path) = RTRIM(Path) ) )
    THEN
      null;

    ELSE
      IF ( UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(arch_file_handle) )
      THEN
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(arch_file_handle);
      END IF;

      /*
      || remember new file/path
      */
      File := New_File;
      Path := New_Path;

      arch_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(Path, File, 'A');
      HISR_DEBUG.p_hisr_debug_out ('ARCHIVE'
            ,': f_hisr_archive_name  '||'  Path: '|| Path ||'...'|| File ,'YES');

    END IF;

    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(arch_file_handle, ARCHIVE_STRING );

    RETURN(1);
```

output file lines:

> 2016/03/03 11:40:05!1!FEP.1.P!FEP!!Master Station!106-GDA DHL connect!
>   The Server startup ILIST was received. An attempt has been made to
>   connect to the Temporal database for DAC History Log storage. The
>   status of the connection is: Successful.!

Comment: Use `utl_fil.put()` instead of `utl_file.put_line()`

Comment: The code you've shown only writes one line to the output file. ???

Comment: Writes a file ok. But inside shows the data in 3 lines. I need, if is posible, see the data  just on a line.

Comment: Does ARCHIVE_STRING have newline characters in it then? Or do you want multiple calls (which open the file in append mode) to continue writing to the same line? In which case using `put()` would still be what you need, but maybe with a newline as the final call?

Comment: using utl_file.put()  does n´t write the file. I see the error: ORA-29285: error de escritura de archivo. Also, I had to change the line : arch_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(Path, File, 'A', 2000);   instead  arch_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(Path, File, 'A');

Comment: With 2000 you'd have to flush more frequently I think (see the usage notes for the procedure). You'd still probably want to write a newline to the file at some point - presumably you're calling the function several times together, so could explicitly write a new line after the last call, and possibly flush then too?

Comment: sorry Alex, but I dont understand you answer.